# jQuery change logo on section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have for so long searched on how to do like this website has done with their logo:

http://www.shiftbrain.co.jp/works/dcc_2015

The logo changes, what I believe on reaching a section. Does anyone know how to make this with jQuery?

Say I have 2 different sections, one with the class "white" and the other with the class "dark". On reaching the "white" section, I'd like a logo to swap to a dark logo and vice versa.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286487/change-logo-on-scroll-jquery

Comment: @oguzhancerit It is not the same effect I was looking for. I need the logo to change based on what section is in the "view" - not on scroll.

Comment: Unless you know SVG (what they're using), the solution @oguzhancerit mentioned should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked website did it with `mix-blend-mode: exclusion`. [Read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) at MDN. In general "the `mix-blend-mode` CSS property describes how an element content should blend with the content of the element that is below it and the element's background".

This is pretty new feature in CSS, so [be aware of the support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode).

**Demo:**

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  color: #FFF;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for your knowledge. Will read about Mix blend mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( "body" ).scroll(function() {
  var section = $( "div#section1" );
  if(is_logo_on_this_section(section.top)){
    change_the_logo(new_url);
  }
});
```

Full Documents you can use:

https://api.jquery.com/position/

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/